# Implementing splitter with no width inside a box

Tags: css, xul, thunderbird

I have a horizontal box consisting of 4 other boxes separated by splitters. I want to use a splitter that looks like the tree-splitter (with no width), but whenever I try to use it, the splitters disappear and the columns cannot be resized. Any ideas why?

Or have you got any idea how I can implement a splitter that would look like one with `id="folderpane_splitter"` that has width probably `1px`? This solution would be perfect for me.

My code looks like:

```
<hbox>
     <hbox flex="10">
         <label value="name1"/>
     </hbox>
     <splitter/>
     <hbox flex="20">
         <label value="name2"/>
     </hbox>
     <splitter/>
     <hbox flex="30"">
         <label value="name3"/>
     </hbox>
     <splitter/>
     <hbox flex="40">
         <label value="name4"/>
     </hbox>
</hbox>
```

If anyone wonders I'm working on an extension for Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
<splitter style="background-image: none; width: 1px; min-width: 1px;"/>
```

gave me the apperance I needed. Probably not overriding min-width was blacking it from getting thinner.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the id="folderpane_splitter" in firefox but it didn't change look. Anyway perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
<splitter style="-moz-appearance: separator;"/>
```

Comment: id="folderpane_splitter" is in Thunderbird not Firefox, and you gave me a great hint- have to check something now :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Trees have [special code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/layout/xul/base/src/tree/src/nsTreeColFrame.cpp#128) to make zero-width splitters work.